# SoftLayer_User_Customer_ApiAuthentication::getUser failed with Exception

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
        "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"

)

func main() {
            // SoftLayer API username and key
            username := "my-username"  // used actual username and api-key
            apikey := "My-APIkey"

            // Create SoftLayer API session
            sess := session.New(username, apikey)

            // Get SoftLayer_Account service
            resp := services.GetUserCustomerApiAuthenticationService(sess)
            users, err := resp.GetUser()
            if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("\n Unable to get users:\n - %s\n", err)
                    return
            }
            fmt.Printf("\n Unable to get users:\n - %s\n", users)
    }
```

=====
$ ./list_user

Unable to get users:

## - SoftLayer_Exception: Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_User_Customer_ApiAuthentication::getUser) (HTTP 500)

I tried the similar code to get object as well. It throws same exception.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is due to that both methods need to use an User_Customer_ApiAuthentication identifier.

You can use the following code on both methods as they will use the same authentication id:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"

  )

  func main() {
        // SoftLayer API username and key
        username := "my-username"  // used actual username and api-key
        apikey := "My-ApiKey"

        // Create SoftLayer API session
        sess := session.New(username, apikey)

        // Get SoftLayer_Account service
        resp := services.GetUserCustomerApiAuthenticationService(sess)
        users, err := resp.Id(123456).GetUser()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("\n Unable to get users:\n - %s\n", err)
                return
        }
        //Following helps to print the result in json format.
        jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(users,"","     ")
        if jsonErr != nil {
               fmt.Println(jsonErr)
               return
        }
        fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

If you need to retrieve the authentication id above, you can use the SoftLayer_User_Customer::getObject method and search for the **apiAuthenticationKeys** relational property that will contain it.